# How to change background color select 2 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

Demo and my code is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/fc1qevem/10/

My javascript code is like this :

```
var select02 = $('#select02');

$(select02).select2({
    data: [{
        id: 0,
        text: "test01"
    }, {
        id: 1,
        text: "test02"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        text: "test03"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        text: "test04"
    }, {
        id: 4,
        text: "test05"
    }],
     placeholder: "Branch name",
});
```

I want change the background color of select2 to blue color

I want change the background color using javascript

Whether it can be done?

Thank you

Comment: .select2-search input{ background-color: blue; } try this in your css

Comment: @Karthikeyan, If css can be placed in javascript?

Comment: $('.select2-selection').css('background-color', 'blue'); @moses t you can try this.

Answer (score 2):

add this in your css

```
.select2-selection{
  background-color:blue !important;
}
```

js solution

```
 $(select02).select2({
    data: [{
        id: 0,
        text: "test01"
    }, {
        id: 1,
        text: "test02"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        text: "test03"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        text: "test04"
    }, {
        id: 4,
        text: "test05"
    }],
     placeholder: "Branch name",
}).data("select2").$container.find(".select2-selection").css('background-color', 'blue');
```

Comment: If css can be placed in javascript?

Comment: Thank you.I thought this would be easy to find, but apparently it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I use it this way and it works very well:

```
$("#select02").siblings('.select2').children('.selection').children('.select2-selection').css('background-color', 'blue')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you will change the background-color using **JavaScript** try this:

$('.select2-selection').css('background-color', 'blue');

Answer (score 0):

```
// Css code
.bg_color {
     background-color: blue !important;
}

// Javascript code
// just put this code under the load function

$(select02).select2({ containerCssClass: "bg_color " });
```

This is how select2 adding class to the container or default css ".select2-container--default .select2-selection--single" of select2 where you can edit the background color of the container. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Try the code below:-

```
document.getElementById("select02").style.backgroundColor="blue";
```